# Set PAGE_NOACCESS & VirtualLock on memory region on windows

Tags: windows, segmentation-fault, kernel, signals, virtual-memory

On the [documentation page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366895(v=vs.85).aspx) for VirtualLock is the following remark:

```
Memory protected with PAGE_NOACCESS cannot be locked.
```

Is there some way around this? The feat is possible on unix systems but there exists this limitation on windows. The goal is to prevent memory being paged to disk while simultaneously preventing any kinda access to it.

Comment: no, this mean that when you call `VirtualProtect` with `PAGE_NOACCESS` it implicitly unlock pages. even after you return to old protect - pages already not locked and can be paged to disk.  `PAGE_NOACCESS` not prevent paged. visa versa - it force unlock pages and enable it swap to disk

Comment: so call to `VirtualProtect(pv, cb, PAGE_NOACCESS, *)` on locked pages by fact have effect like you call `VirtualUnlock(pv, cb);` too

Comment: Is there another way to ensure that values are not paged while still making read/write/execute access to the memory region trigger a sigsegv. As is possible on linux.

Comment: no any sigsegv in windows. and your question unclear. for what you need lock pages ? if memory address is valid - you can read (or write if it writable), even if paged to disk. of course in this case cpu generate exception, because virtual address not valid, but windows in kernel handle this exception, load data from disk to memory.

Comment: The application is in security and the values in memory cannot be written to disk . At the same time all rwx+ access has to be prevented. This doesn't seem to be possible on windows if I am understanding correctly?

Comment: if you have `SE_LOCK_MEMORY_PRIVILEGE` you can call `VirtualLock` for prevent swap memory to page file. so in what is problem ? you know this at very begin. if want lock memory - you can do this

Comment: The problem is I also want to set NOACCESS

Comment: Could I set PAGE_GUARD on the memory region instead and catch the STATUS_GUARD_PAGE_VIOLATION? Would the data remain intact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190516/discussion-between-rbmm-and-awn).

Comment: however if you call `NtProtectVirtualMemory` on locked memory range - return code will be `STATUS_WAS_UNLOCKED` - *The page protection of a locked page was changed to 'No Access' and the page was unlocked from memory and from the process.* - which clear say that page no more locked after this. the same status will be for `PAGE_GUARD`. so after you try one of this 2 protections on page - you **unlock** page as side effect

Comment: but *preventing any kinda access to it.* - what sense in this ? even if assume you do this, possible do remove this too. so in what sense ?

Answer (score 3):

when we call [`ZwProtectVirtualMemory`](https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker/blob/master/phnt/include/ntzwapi.h#L2524) on locked memory region with `PAGE_NOACCESS` or `PAGE_GUARD|*` the returned status was `STATUS_WAS_UNLOCKED` :

> {Page Unlocked}
>
> The page protection of a locked page was changed to
>   'No Access' and the page was unlocked from memory and from the
>   process.

here important call exactly `ZwProtectVirtualMemory` instead `VirtualProtect[Ex]` because this win32 api does not distinguish between different [`NT_SUCCESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-ntstatus-values) values, simply return *true* on any of it and drop original status. but `STATUS_WAS_UNLOCKED` was defined as `0x40000017L` also  `NT_SUCCESS` value - so `VirtualProtect[Ex]` **lost** important information in this case.

so set `PAGE_NOACCESS` or `PAGE_GUARD|*` as side effect unlock page from memory

but what sense set `PAGE_NOACCESS` on page ? for prevent somebody external for read data from page ? but if this agent have access to your process - he can and remove this `PAGE_NOACCESS` too, if have no access - not need and do protection. in both case - senseless set `PAGE_NOACCESS` - it or not need or can be removed anyway.

prevent page swap to page file exist sense, because in theory it can be read from it, after system shutdown (if it will be here at this moment), but set No Access (this remove valid bit from *PTE* entry for this page) no sense

simply code for test

```
void PrintNtStatus(PCSTR prefix, NTSTATUS status)
{
    static HMODULE hmod = 0;

    if (!hmod)
    {
        hmod = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll");
    }

    PWSTR msg;
    if (FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_HMODULE|FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, hmod, status, 0, (PWSTR)&msg, 0, 0))
    {
        DbgPrint("%s = %x(%S)\n", prefix, status, msg);
        LocalFree(msg);
    }
}

void LockTest()
{
    if (PVOID pv = VirtualAlloc(0, 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE))
    {
        if (VirtualLock(pv, 1))
        {
            ULONG op;
            SIZE_T size = 1;
            PVOID BaseAddress = pv;
            //STATUS_WAS_UNLOCKED
            PrintNtStatus("ProtectVirtualMemory", 
                ZwProtectVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, &size, PAGE_NOACCESS, &op));
            PrintNtStatus("ProtectVirtualMemory", 
                ZwProtectVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &BaseAddress, &size, op, &op));
            PrintNtStatus("VirtualUnlock", VirtualUnlock(pv, 1) ? STATUS_SUCCESS : RtlGetLastNtStatus());
        }
        VirtualFree(pv, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    }
}
```